# Bootstrap: Full Screen Row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my blog http://www.lowcoupling.com based on Twitter Bootstrap
I'd like to have the bottom row (currently containing my latest tweets) full screen wide as the carousel at the top.
How should I do that?

Comment: I would start by moving your tweets section outside of your `.container`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do that by removing "container" class from the tweets div.

Answer (score 3):

Change `col-lg-6` to `col-lg-12` preferably  `col-lg-11`, override `float:left` and add `margin:0 auto`